# batch file to track information and open external excel 2010 file with vba

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a `batch` file that when it is run captures the windows login, date, and time.  I would like to place a counter in the `batch` that tracks if the batch file was opened and increments by 1 if the answer to the second question (in bold) is "y".  If the counter is `= 1` then a message displays with a message along with the username, date, and time (in italics).  If the answer to either of the questions is "n" then the "goodbye" is displayed and the `batch` closes. I am getting syntax errors and need some help.  Thank you :).

**new batch file**

```
@ECHO OFF
:: ask user 
:choice
set /P c=Has the check been done [y/n]
if /i %c%==y (
set /P c=Do you want to send the DOSE report[y/n]?
) 
:: count loop
set var1=0
:loop
set /a var1=%var1%+1
if %var1% EQU 1 (
goto :end
) else (
goto :loop
)
:end
echo "the DOSE report has already been sent by %USERNAME% on %DATE% at %TIME%"
else if /i not %c% ==n goto goodbye
if /i %c%==y ( 
"L:\NGS\HLA LAB\total quality management\QC & QA\DOSE reports\DOSE reporting form.xlsm"
) else if /i not %c%==n goto goodbye
:goodbye
echo "Goodbye"
TIMEOUT 2 /nobreak
exit
end
```

**Current display on screen**

```
1
"the DOSE report has already been sent by cmccabe on Tue 10/27/2015 at   11:00:20.
21"
Has the check been done [y/n]
```

Comment: What syntax errors do you get? Which line of code generates the errors? Why did you tag this question as excel-vba?

Comment: I added a section of the screen output and was able to correct the syntax errors but the `1` should not be seen and only increment if the answer to the second question is "y".  The `xlsm` that gets called in the `batch` is a `vba` that uses excel 2010 button to run it.  Thank you :).

Comment: Either add the VBA code (if you have issues with it) or remove the `excel-vba` tag.

Comment: There are no issues with the `excel-vba` and  I will remove the tag.  I apologize and thank you :).

Comment: Your logic will never goto goodbye because it is checking IF the answer is NOT EQUAL to N.  Also, close up the space between your comparisons.

Comment: @Squashman I made some edits to the code and now get to the goodbye, however the display on the screen is still the same.  Thank you :).

Comment: @Chris, then change your code above and remove those asterisks in your code as well.

Comment: @Squashman I updated the code and removed the asterisks.  Thank you :).

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite understanding your description of your program but I am die hard fan of a specific formatting and syntax of batch files.  I receive no syntax errors when I execute your code like this.

```
@ECHO OFF
:: count loop
set var1=0
:loop
set /a var1=%var1%+1

echo %var1%

if %var1% EQU 1 (
    goto end
) else (
    goto loop
)
:end
echo "the DOSE report has already been sent by %USERNAME% on %DATE% at   %TIME%"

:: ask user 
:choice
set /P c=Has the check been done [y/n]
if /i %c%==y (
    set /P c=Do you want to send the DOSE report[y/n]?
) else (
    if /i %c%==n goto goodbye
)
if /i %c%==y ( 
    ECHO "L:\NGS\HLA LAB\total quality management\QC & QA\DOSE reports\DOSE reporting    form.xlsm"
) else (
    if /i %c%==n goto goodbye
)
:goodbye
echo "goodbye"
pause
```

Comment: I do not get any syntax error either anymore.  What I am trying to do is only increment the counter if `set /P c=Do you want to send the DOSE report[y/n]?` is "y". if the answer to either `set /P c=Has the check been done [y/n]` or `set /P c=Do you want to send the DOSE report[y/n]?` is "n" then the `batch` goes to goodbye (which I think it does).  Thank you :).

Comment: @Chris So what is stopping you from putting in another SET /A to increment the counter?

Comment: I just noticed the `echo %var1%` is causing the `1` to be displayed. How do I set the %var1% to only increment if  `set /P c=Do you want to send the DOSE report[y/n]?` is "y"?  Should I SET /A on that line? Thank you very much :).

Comment: I edited the code in the post with the change, is this what you mean?  Thank you :).

Comment: @Chris, I am not really understanding what the logic decision process is for your program.  Not sure why I am not understanding what you are trying to do.  Gonna have to bow out of this question.

Comment: No worries I am going to re-post a, hopefully cleaner version with better logic... thank you :).